# Automatically mounting available partition of SD card

Tags: linux, sd-card, fstab

| SD card Type | Partition available | Size of Partition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | mmcblk0p1, mmcblk0p2 | mmcblk0p1: 30Mb, mmcblk0p2: 31Gb |
| B | mmcblk0p1 | mmcblk0p1: 31Gb |

I am using a linux system where I need to mount the largest available SD card partition block automatically during boot. I am able to mount a specific partition eg. /dev/mmcblk0p2 by adjusting /etc/fstab. But this does not work if I change the type of SD card, eg. using type B SD card instead of type A.

Is there a way to mount the largest available partition block automatically irrespective of  the type used?.

Type is simply used here for explanation purpose. Basically type A is a formatted SD with burned images whereas type B is fresh new SD card.

Any feedback or solution will help a lot. Thank you all.

Comment: Considering that fstab works at partitions level, I think it's not possible. For sure it's possible to write a script that watch if a disk is plugged and mount only the largest partition. Does that help you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So a script can be used to decide which partition needs to used  during system boot up right?. Do you know where the script should be added or how can it be used to do the check during every boot?.

Comment: I think there are two options: 1) passing init=script parameter to your kernel on grub (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65207/running-a-script-as-grub-boot-option) or the way I would, make a service run before mount/fstab try 2) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246935/set-systemd-service-to-execute-after-fstab-mount.

Answer (score 2):

I made a script and service to achieve it as I was quite interested on this subject.

The script is selecting the largest partition on `/dev/sdb`, so if your device has another identification it has to be changed to reflect your env.

### My environment

- Ubuntu Server on VirtualBox
- 8GB USB stick with 2 partitions

### The script

Path: /opt/usb_mount_script.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

partition="/dev/$(lsblk -x size -i -n | grep -Po 'sdb[0-9]+.*' | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"

sudo mount "$partition" /mnt/usb_largest_partition

exit 0
```

### Explanation

- `lsblk -x size -i -n` => list all partitions, sort by size, ASCII mode and no header
- `grep -Po 'sdb[0-9]+.*'` => filter the partitions by device sdb
- `tail -n 1` => get the last line
- `cut -d ' ' -f 1` => get the partition name

### The service

Path: /etc/systemd/system/test.service

```
[Unit]
Descriptionn=mount largest partition at boot time
After=mnt-wibble.mount

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/usb_mount_script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### Setup

- create the service
- create the script
- allow execution on the script: `sudo chmod +x usb_mount_script.sh`
- create the mount dir: `mkdir /mnt/usb_largest_partition`
- install the service: `sudo systemctl enable test`
- run the service manually with `systemctl start test`
- boot up your system with the sdcard/usb plugged in

Comment: It's a bad idea to use `sudo` inside such a script, as you don't know where the standard input and output will be connected.  Instead, configure the service to run it as root, and use `su` to selectively drop privileges where necessary.  It's also better to be honest when it fails, instead of `exit 0`.